# Unable To Read a downloaded doc file on iOS

Tags: c#, ios, uiwebview, download, doc

I am using xamarin.ios with c#, I download a file (with byte arrary) and store it. But doc files cant be readable. I have this error.

[image]

When I download pdf, png file, they are ok. but for doc, its problem..

If I copy a doc file to directory of application on ios simulator, the file is readable. but downloaded file seems weird. like this

[image]

I think it downloads right, otherwise the downloaded file cant be opened.

```
   return await Task.Run(()=>service.DownloadVersion(ref result[0]));
```

I download document with that code. It returns a byte arrary. after I save it like that

```
var result = await downloadDocument.Download(viewDocumentProfile);
saveDocumentToDownloadFolder(result,String.Format("{0}-#{1}-{2}-{3}.{4}",
viewDocumentProfile.Library.LoginInfo.LibraryName,viewDocumentProfile.DocNumber,"v1",  
viewDocumentProfile.DocName,viewDocumentProfile.ApplicationExtension));
```

and I display the file like that

```
     private void ShowDocument(string filename)
    {
        webviewDocument.LoadRequest(new NSUrlRequest(new NSUrl(filename, false)));
       webviewDocument.ScalesPageToFit = true;
    }
```

To display files, I use webview. So where is my mistake?